# Vim signature function in status line instead of preview window

Tags: vim

I switched from PhpStorm to Vim and everything it's ok except one thing.

Autocomplete work fine with phpcomplete, phpctags and neocomplete, the signature of function is visible in complete menu, but when I accept the suggestion in the menu, the signature disappear.

It's possible to add preview to completeopt to show the signature in top split window but I don't like it because it take too much space on the screen.

It would be great to show the signature at the bottom of the screen in the status line instead of the preview window.

Does anyone know how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found exactly what I was looking for.
Shougo the developer of neocomplete provide the [echodoc](https://github.com/Shougo/echodoc.vim) plugin that works like a charm with [neocomplete](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim) and phpcomplete or Eclim.
Thanks to him.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it.

Use VIM [TagList plugin](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net), which allows to show function signatures on status bar.

Check the [tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/04/ctags-taglist-vi-vim-editor-as-sourece-code-browser/).

Comment: Thank you but this plugin requires too much action.